# How to make headful puppeteer chrome view only

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am searching for several hours and couldn't find a way to make headful puppeteer chrome just view only. Is there any way I can do something and chrome becomes view only so user cannot interact with it.

The behaviour I am looking is similar to (this is pseudo code):

```
// Some code
// Please log in using the opened screen( Headful Chrome )
page.viewOnly(false) 
// User interacts with headful chrome.
page.viewOnly(true)
// User cannot interact with headful chrome anymore, can only watch.
```

Comment: What would be `viewOnly`? Is it something that Chromium provides?

Comment: No, it is an example code to show what i wanted to achieve. I'll emphasize it better.

Comment: We don't have that feature either on Puppeteer nor Chromium.

Comment: Can the same feature achieved by adding some things to the DOM, or by injecting JS in a way it will not break the clicks/types from puppeteer.